# Select with a set of predefined values in JOOQ for PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, select, jooq

Does anybody know is it possible to write in JOOQ select with a set of predefined values? I need it for insert if not exists.
For example,

```
INSERT INTO test
    (text)
    SELECT '1234567890123456789'
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT id FROM test WHERE text = '1234567890123456789'
        );
```

Comment: For the record, this question has been [cross posted also to the jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/OlIOeEQQpec/7woMPgl8JIIJ)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by myself:

```
List<Param<?>> params = new LinkedList<>();
params.add(DSL.val("1234567890123456789"));

List<Field<?>> fields = new LinkedList<>();
fields.add(TEST.TEXT);

SelectConditionStep<Record1<TEXT>> notExistsSelect = context.select(TEST.TEXT).from(TEST).where(TEST.TEXT.eq("1234567890123456789"));
SelectConditionStep<Record> insertIntoSelect = context.select(params).whereNotExists(notExistsSelect);

context.insertInto(TEST, fields).select(insertIntoSelect).execute();
```

But it would be great, if we had an ability to do it via **InsertQuery**. I've not found the way to do it.